# How to run a python script on a remote ec2 instance using sudo from pycharm

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pycharm, sudo

I am running pycharm 2017.2.3. I want to run my python script on a remote ec2 instance using sudo user through pycharm. How do I acieve this?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you actually want to use `root` privileges in automation. For almost everything that you can do as root, there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer after a researching through the internet. We can have a script on remote machine as a pycharm interpreter. Create a following script on a remote machine and make sure the script is executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /usr/bin/python "$@"
```

Now change the project interpreter to point to the above script on remote machine in pycharm. Now every script you run on local machine gets executed on remote as a sudo user.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps below:

1. Go to `File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter` and add a new interpreter
2. Click on `+` to add a new python interpreter and then click on `SSH interpreter`
3. Provide your `EC2 Public DNS` in HOST and `ubuntu` as `username`
4. Click `Next` and add the `private_key.pem` file.

See this article for more details:
[PyCharm setup for AWS automatic deployment](https://www.codementor.io/abhishake/pycharm-setup-for-aws-automatic-deployment-m7n8uu2n4)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can configure your python interpreter over SSH with the professional version of PyCharm.

[Configuring Remote Interpreter + PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html)